# Check if attachment in SPD Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, attachments, office-365

Is it possible to check if an attachment is attached to the current listitem?
I can check if Attachments equals or not equals to a value, but not if empty.
What value should I fill in then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, Stupid question... I can choose "Yes"
So "If attachements equals yes" does the trick.